# Trying to run 'npm install --save-dev paraviewweb' on my machine, and I keep running into an error at canvas@1.6.11 install

Tags: windows, npm, node-gyp, paraview

There seems to be an issue with my windows build tools ( I already re-installed and updated it ) and I installed the gyp packages too. However Im currently stuck getting this error after trying to run the above command. What is the issue and how can I fix it?

[image: Here is the error log]

Answer (score 0):

```
npm config set msvs_version 2015 --global
npm install -g node-sass
```

running these commands in the directory solves this issue.

https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/119#issuecomment-318609877

credit to this person.